# Should httpClient be injected Maui c# or should the service be a singleton

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui

I am building a mobile app and I need to make http calls to apis, naturally I thought I would inject the httpclient but then reading articles like https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66863

I decided against it, I have always read the HttpClient should be instantiated only once when starting up the app but after reading that article I will make

```
       private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

       public MyService()
       {
           this.httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(Config.APIUrl) };
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-version", "1.0");
       }
```

How and when do you instantiate the httpClient?

Comment: If you're able to, use `IHttpClientFactory`

Comment: I thought that contrary to general belief is not as efficient as people think